# Ignore symbol/icons/small images with Tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Tesseract has done a great job in my images however there a small details that I'd like to fix and make it 100%.

I want to ignore this icon in Tesseract process, I even don't want to know if there is something.

[image]

This symbol sometimes is converted to either numbers or letters. I've tried to use the white list but it haven't solved it.

I have found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995023/train-tesseract-to-label-icons), but I'd like to know if this is the best option that I can work on or if there is something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different approach to deal with those icons.

I used Imagemagick in ruby called RMagick which draw a rectangle on the image covering all icons and also the code bellow colorize the image to black and white.

```rb
require 'rmagick'

class PdfConverter
  include Magick

  def process_image
    pdf_path = 'file.pdf'
    pdf_image = Magick::Image.read(pdf_path) do |options|
      options.density = 400
    end

    pdf_image.each_with_index do |image, i|
      canvas = Magick::Image.new(image.columns, image.rows) do |options|
        options.background_color = 'white'
      end

      # Composite the PDF image on the canvas with alpha handling
      canvas.composite!(image, 0, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
      canvas.alpha(Magick::DeactivateAlphaChannel)
      canvas = canvas.quantize(2, Magick::GRAYColorspace)

      gc = Magick::Draw.new

      gc.fill_opacity(1)
      gc.fill('white')

      # Draw rectangle
      gc.rectangle(1100, 1000, 1200, 4000)
      gc.draw(canvas)

      # Save the resulting image as "b.png"
      canvas.write("public/uploads/#{i}colorize.png")
    end
  end
end
```